# jQuery UI widget mouse event get at the Widget state?

Tags: jquery-ui

With the jQuery UI Widget factory pattern (1.8), I'm having trouble finding the widget object itself while in a mouse event:

```
$.widget('foo.myWidget', {
  _create: function() {
    var $container = this.element.wrap('<div class="ui-widget" />').parent(); // Create a widget container
    $container.append('<div class="myWidgetControl" />'); // Add some clickable thing
    $container.find('.myWidgetControl').on('mouseup.myWidget', this._handleClick); // Watch the mouse event
  },
  options: { // Widget factory options object
    secretKey: 'foobar'
  },
  _handleClick: function(e) {
    // User clicked on ".myWidgetControl"
    // this == DOM element .myWidgetControl
    // e == the jQuery event object

    // I need to get options.secretKey; how do I find it?!?
  }
});
```

In the above example, how do I get the "secretKey" option parameter? Given that there might be multiple instances of this widget on the page, how do I get the proper instance for the control element the user clicked?

The 'widget' method [added in 1.8](http://jqueryui.com/docs/Upgrade_Guide#New_Widget_Method) looks like it might be a solution, but it requires knowing what element the user originally applied the widget to:

```
$("#myDiv").myWidget("widget");
```

In that case, how do you find out what the user originally set as the selector for this instance of the widget ("#myDiv" in the example)?

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution at [this blog post](http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/tips-for-developing-jquery-ui-widgets/) (leaving this question open to see if there's a better way, though):

As the widget developer, I know what the container element is; therefore, use the [jQuery Data cache](http://api.jquery.com/data/) to save a reference to the widget so I can find it later:

```
_create: function() {
  /* existing code */
  var $container = this.element.wrap('<div class="ui-widget" />').parent();
  $container.data('widget', this); // Save for later
},
_handleClick: function(e) {
  var $container = $(this).parentsUntil('.ui-widget').parent(); // Traverse the tree to find the root element I saved the data for
  var widget = $container.data('widget');
  alert(widget.options.secretKey); // Success! (Don't actually display your secretKey in an alert...)
}
```